# Can't fetch 'channel_list' in Python

Tags: python, slack, slack-api

I am using Slack + Python and trying to fetch `channel_list` after authenticating with Slack user. But the application can't allow them to choose a channel in `channel_list`. I use [python_slackclient](https://github.com/slackapi/python-slackclient)

> AttributeError: 'WebClient' object has no attribute 'channels'

This is code:
Slack api client

```py
def fetch_channels():
  client = slack.WebClient(token=current_user.token) 
  channels = client.channels.list
  return channels
  ## <bound method WebClient.channels_list of <slack.web.client.WebClient object at XXXXXXX>>

  return channels
```

View

```py
<select name="channel">
  {% for channel in channels %}
  <option value="{ channel.name }">{ channel.name }</option>
  {% endfor %}
</select>
```

via [Channel List](https://api.slack.com/methods/channels.list)

Comment: Because there is no such method in slack. It is channels.list not channels_list

Comment: Thanks for your comment @AdamStrauss. I have updated `client.channels` but this error occurs: `AttributeError: 'WebClient' object has no attribute 'channels'`

Comment: client.channels.list() try this.

Comment: Hmm. same error `'WebClient' object has no attribute 'channels'`

Comment: try this client = slack.WebClient(token=current_user.token)

Comment: Thanks for advice. I really appreciate it but the same error ...

Comment: then what about the token? is it really creating an client?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason you are getting this error is that the name of the method is spelled incorrectly.

While the API endpoint is called [`channels.list`](https://api.slack.com/methods/channels.list), the method of the class WebClient is called `channels_list`. Also it's a method, so you need to call it with parenthesis. Finally it won't return the list of channels directly, but a dict that includes the list of channels as the property names `channels`.

Btw. You can see all parameters and what the methods return in the description of the API endpoint.

Here is a corrected version of your code:

```
response = client.channels_list()
assert(response['ok'])
channels = response['channels']
```